# Filing for unemployment due to COVID-19 start date pushed back

Tags: united-states, new-job, start-date, covid-19

I've read other individuals post in regards to their similar situation however I do not see them state what I am looking for so hopefully someone can answer my question.

I was supposed to start working with my new employer on 13th of April 2020 however a few days prior to the start date I was told that my start date will be pushed to August due to the virus. They did not have an exact start date, just knew it would be in August.

When applying for unemployment benefits since I am covered under the CARES act (I live in the US) it is asking me to enter the dates of your last employment. However I am a bit confused what should I enter in the start and end section. Should I enter "4/13/20" for both start and end date?

[image: Dates Worked for Last Employer | Enter the dates of your last employment. Choose "01" from the "Day" dropdown box as the first date worked if you do not remember the exact date. | First Date You Worked: * [Month] [Day] Year: [] (If you have worked for this employer before, provide the start date of the most recent employment period.) Last date You Worked: * [Month] [Day] Year: []]

Comment: Is there a support for this thing? Like someone in charge of the website you could ask?

Comment: which state are you in?

Comment: also, given the situation there should be a coronavirus tag. and i don't think this question should be marked for closure at all.

Comment: @bharal I am in Texas

Answer (score 3):

> Should I enter "4/13/20" for both start and end date?

Unless you actually worked on 4/13/20, you should not use that for a start or end date.

Instead, you should be using the dates from your previous job, not one that hasn't yet started.

Note that the form says "Enter the dates of your **last employment**".

If this doesn't work, then you'll need to call your local unemployment office.

Comment: I see, however whenever I enter the date from my last employer (1/14/19) the system tells me Last Date You Worked: Cannot be more than 1 year ago. I did not have a job lined up until this new employer came around which I then signed the offer letter for the start date of 4/13/20.

Comment: @alphaX - Sounds like you were not employed on 4/13/2020 which is one of the requirements for the unemployment aid from the CARES act.  You only get unemployment aid if specific conditions are meet for a period of time.  If you were unemployed in January 2020 it’s unlikely you qualify for unemployment aid in April 2020 from a job you held in Jan 2019.